# performance of unpack combined with join in Perl

Tags: performance, perl, join, unpack

I have a parser written in Perl which parses file of fixed length records. Part of the record consists of several strings (also fixed length), made of numbers only. Each character in the string is encoded as number, not as ASCII char. I.e., if I have string 12345, it's encoded as 01 02 03 04 05 (instead of 31 32 33 34 35).

I parse the record with unpack, and this particular part is unpacked as `@array = unpack "C44", $s`. Then I recover needed string with simple join, like `$m = join("", @array)`.

I was wondering if thats an optimal way to decode. Files are quite big, millions of records, and obviously I tried to look if it's possible to optimize. Profiler shows that most of the time is spent in parsing the records (i.e., reading, writing, and other stuff is not a problem), and in parsing most of the time has been taken by these joins. I remember from other sources that join is quite efficient operation. Any ideas if it's possible to speed code more or is it optimal already? Perhaps it would be possible to avoid this intermediate array in some clever way, e.g., use pack/unpack combination instead?

**Edited: code example**

The code which I try to optimise looks like this:

```
    while (read(READ, $buf, $rec_l) == $rec_l) {
        my @s = unpack "A24 C44 H8", $buf;
        my $msisdn = substr $s[0], 0, 11;
        my $address = join("", @s[4..14]);
        my $imsi = join("", @s[25..39]);
        my $ts = localtime(hex($s[45]));
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Untested (I'll come back and edit when I'm less busy) but this should work if I've done all of the math correctly, and be faster:

```
my ($msisdn, $address, $imsi, $ts) = 
    unpack "A11 x13 x3 a10 x10 a15 x5 N", $buf;
$address |= "0" x 10;
$imsi |= "0" x 15
$ts = localtime($ts);
```

Comment: Only small correction was needed, besides that this one works correct. And twice as fast as mine. Looking into this unpack I wonder myself how I managed to come up with these joins :(

Comment: @MariusM if you tell me what the correction is, I'll be happy to edit my answer.

Comment: `hex unpack 'H8'` is a very roundabout way of doing `unpack 'N'`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As always in Perl, faster is less readable :-)

```
join("", unpack("C44", $s))
```

I don't believe this change would speed up your code. Everything depends on how often you call the join function to read one whole file. If you're working in chunks, try to increase the size of them. If you're doing some operation between unpack and join to this array, try to line them up with a map operation. If you post your source code it would be easier to identify the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a pack/unpack noob, but how about skipping the join by altering your sample code like so:

```
my $m = unpack "H*", $s ;
```

quick test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use Test::More tests => 1 ;

is( unpack("H*", "\x12\x34\x56"),"123456");
```